# I can not insert a row into the table using syslog-ng

Tags: database, postgresql, syslog-ng

```
destination d_pgsql {
 sql(type(pgsql)
 host("ip.of.you.host") username("logwriter")
 password(“logwriterpassword") port("5432")
 database("syslog")
 table("logs_${HOST}_${R_YEAR}${R_MONTH}${R_DAY}")
 columns("datetime varchar(16)", "host varchar(32)", "program varchar(20)", "pid
 varchar(10)", "message varchar(800)")
 values("$R_DATE", "$HOST", "$PROGRAM", "$PID", "$MSG")
 indexes("datetime", "host", "program", "pid", "message"));
 };

log { source(src); destination(d_pgsql); };
```

When try to restart, syslog-ng gets the error:

```
[2018-11-14T15:38:57.863699] Unable to initialize database access (DBI); rc='-1', error='No such file or directory (2)'
[2018-11-14T15:38:57.863877] Error initializing message pipeline; plugin_name='sql', location='/usr/local/etc/syslog-ng.conf:49:5'
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/syslog-ng: WARNING: failed to start syslog_ng
```

I have already read other posts on the internet, everyone suggested checking if libdb is installed. I have it. So what could it be? I do not have an idea anymore. I am using FreeBSD.

Comment: Have you also checked the pgsql driver is also installed ?
Can you connect to the database with other tools from that machine ?

Could you please start syslog-ng with -Fdev (foreground and increased log level) ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have libdb-driver. Thank you very much.